# Changing unicode encodings in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am writing a simple module that needs to handle German letters eg ASCII 132. I have read most of the advice given on this site and others on how to handle unicode and encodings in Python2.x However, things do not work out for me. Example

```
    >>> import sys,unicodedata
    >>> x='a'
    >>> u=unicode(x,'utf-8')
    >>> unicodedata.category(u)
    'Ll'
    >>> y=u.encode('latin-1') #to turn string into bytes
    >>> y=y.decode('utf-8') # to turn bytes back to strin but encoded utf-8
    >>> unicodedata.category(y)
    'Ll'
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I change the encoding to utf8?

By the way I had copied a file called sitecustomize.py which was supposed to make the default encoding to utf-8.  Sys.getdefaultcode() in fact shows utf-8 as the default encoding, belive it or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ASCII 132, ASCII only goes up to 127. U+0084 (Unicode 132) is a control character and cp1252 0x84 (132 in Windows Western European) is `„` which isn't a letter, so I'm not sure what character you're talking about.

```
>>> y=u.encode('latin-1') #to turn string into bytes
>>> y=y.decode('utf-8') # to turn bytes back to strin but encoded utf-8
```

> Why can't I change the encoding to utf8?

Python2 `str` is a series of bytes; `unicode` is a series of characters. There is no ‘encoding’ attached to either of them; an encoding is what you use to map between the two. Encoding some characters to Latin-1 and then decoding them as if they were UTF-8 doesn't leave you with a qualitatively different `unicode` string at the end, just a string with mangled characters for all characters that aren't encoded the same in both encodings. That is to say, anything but ASCII.

The character `a` is in ASCII so is unaffected by any encode/decode cycles you inflict on it.

Common German letters are handled fine by `unicodedata`:

```
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\u00E4')  # u'\u00E4'==u'ä'
'Ll'
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\u00E4'.upper())  # -> u'\u00C4'==u'Ä'
'Lu'
```

Keep data in your program in `unicode` string format; `decode` it from byte input and encode it to byte output (eg for file I/O) only when you need to.

Best not fiddle with the default encoding—it probably won't do what you think. Instead be explicit about what encoding you want any time you move from bytes to characters or vice versa. And be aware that if you're using the Windows console, non-ASCII I/O probably won't work at all.

Comment: @Mark: d'oh! I doubly can't count. ta :-)